# Why did this js Fizzbuzz question get so many more views than others?

Tags: discussion, questions, twitter

Why did [this recent question: *FizzBuzz in Javascript*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/211113/120114) get so many views and, presumably, many more votes (than would be normal)?

My initial theory was that it contains the tags [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) and that tag combined with [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) possibly caused the situation, though [I created a related question with those same tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/211731/120114) (plus a couple others) and, at the time of writing, it has fewer than 1% as many views (i.e. 57 compared to 7,830).

I did notice that the aforementioned question was migrated from SO, and there was [a Great answer tweet](https://twitter.com/StackCodeReview/status/1082925059600191488) for [the answer by Paul](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/211115/120114). Though, there are tweets for the majority of new CR posts on that same feed, including the latter post I mentioned.

When [searching for those two tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz+javascript) I see that the former question is the second highest voted question, and others that have similar number of votes are a bit older (e.g. by 3-4 years).

I also [reviewed an unanswered question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/127212/120114) with those tags and, per habit/progress towards the Illuminator badge, edited that question which should make it appear in the active view of questions, yet views of that question don't seem to have gone up by much.

Is there intelligence from Mod/10k tools, or other analysis tools, that could show why the former post has so many more views that I would have expected? Did the question appear in the list of *Hot Network Questions* across network sites?

Comment: The following javascript question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/216648/120556 shot to 940 views within 22 hours of being posted, now at 1134 views in under 48 hours.

Comment: Yes- it [also became a _Hot Network Question_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/216648/revisions#spacer-e2039d60-34d3-4d4e-aa9a-e717ec48778e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have access to any mod tools, but looking at the Edit History does have one detail:

[image: Edit History]

Generally, questions that are tweeted are approaching, or have gone, **HNQ status**. Chances are that activity on the question triggered a tweet, which triggered high views, possible HNQ, and as a result, high upvotes.

As a note: one answer on it (the one at 47 votes, as of my writing) is a **very** good answer, and includes highly effective code-snippets. Again, I don't have details of the algorithms, but chances are that *definitely* helped garner many views / votes over a short period, which also helped push it into potential HNQ status.

Edit: [one of the mods](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37660/vogel612) indicated that it [looks like it was HNQ before the tweet](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9068/why-did-this-js-fizzbuzz-question-get-so-many-more-views-than-others#comment19164_9070):

> AFAICT from the mod timeline I'd guess that it was HNQ even before it was tweeted

Comment: This many views? Absolutely had HNQ status for at least half a day. Fizzbuzz questions always do well once they hit HNQ.

Comment: AFAICT from the mod timeline I'd guess that it was HNQ even before it was tweeted

Comment: @Vogel612 Had a suspicion -- don't have access to complex enough information to really gauge that, but nice to have that (partially) confirmed. :)

Comment: Per [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279509/341145), I verified via [the web archive for that day](https://web.archive.org/web/20190109005452/https://stackexchange.com/)... apparently [since Feb 28, 2019 this info will appear in the post revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324644/341145)